# How to remove Local Disk entries in DCIM sub-folders in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

in iOS 8, multiple entries of "Local Disk" spawned every time I use Windows 7 File Explorer to transfer files to my computer.

[image]

How to remove those? and when will iPhone / iOS re-index those random sub-folders in DCIM folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings > Safari > Advanced > Website Data > Remove All Website Data

Worked for me with iOS 8.  Disconnect then reconnect the phone to the PC and all the "Local Disk" rubbish is gone.

Comment: this works perfectly !

Comment: This doesn't work, not at least in Windows 8 and iOS8. I used search for * which lists all photos, videos, folders and "Local Disks". Sorting it by type and then selecting only photos and videos does the job. We lose the iOS folder structure but I did not care for that.

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows 7 iOS 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to remove all website data then do as follows: 
Settings > Safari > Advanced > Website Data > then Edit and proceed to erase each entry looking similar to this "a####.phobos.apple.com" . No more "Local Disk"  and even erased the empty folders. It worked for me.